# write a condition in a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause

```
 select * from( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 1 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column1`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 2 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column2`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 3 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column3`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 4)  ,`value`, null)) AS `column4`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 5 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column5`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 6 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column6`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 7 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column7`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 8 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column8`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 9 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column9`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 10) ,`value`, null)) AS `column10`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 11 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column11`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 0) ,`value`, null)) AS `column12`
    FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1
    GROUP BY `lead_id` ) AS T
```

i want to write a condition to the first select ,,, some thing like

```
 select * from( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 1 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column1`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 2 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column2`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 3 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column3`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 4)  ,`value`, null)) AS `column4`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 5 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column5`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 6 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column6`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 7 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column7`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 8 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column8`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 9 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column9`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 10) ,`value`, null)) AS `column10`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 11 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column11`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 0) ,`value`, null)) AS `column12`
    FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1
    GROUP BY `lead_id` ) where `column1`=2014 ) AS T
```

but this is  said #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias , so how can i write this ?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Assuming MySQL: Could it be that you should use "HAVING" instead of "WHERE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `where` clause *after* giving the subquery a name:

```
 select * from( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 1 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column1`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 2 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column2`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 3 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column3`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 4)  ,`value`, null)) AS `column4`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 5 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column5`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 6 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column6`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 7 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column7`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 8 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column8`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 9 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column9`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 10) ,`value`, null)) AS `column10`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 11 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column11`
         , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 0) ,`value`, null)) AS `column12`
    FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1
    GROUP BY `lead_id` )  AS T
    where `column1`=2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to alias all your subqueries, in this case everything inside the first FROM(). Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 1 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column1`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 2 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column2`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 3 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column3`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 4)  ,`value`, null)) AS `column4`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 5 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column5`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 6 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column6`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 7 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column7`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 8 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column8`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 9 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column9`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 10) ,`value`, null)) AS `column10`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 11 ) ,`value`, null)) AS `column11`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF((`id`%12 = 0) ,`value`, null)) AS `column12`
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1
GROUP BY `lead_id` ) AS T WHERE `column1`=2014
```